# Can't withdraw a Candy Machine

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I can't withdraw any of my CMs. I've got timeout error every time I try. I've tried multiple times for several days but result is the same. The result is the same using `withdraw_all` and `withdraw` commands.

Command:

```
ts-node C:/Users/admin/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts withdraw_all -e mainnet-beta -k Se4Gf2GsjgzZZyUfnhFVzVLcijsCXx5a9Erhsp5uoUF.json
```

Result:

```
wallet public key: Se4Gf2GsjgzZZyUfnhFVzVLcijsCXx5a9Erhsp5uoUF
(node:15300) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15300) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
Total Number of Candy Machine Config Accounts to drain 2
1.98635488 SOL locked up in configs
WARNING: This command will drain ALL of the Candy Machine config accounts that are owned by your current KeyPair, this will break your Candy Machine if its still in use
Rejecting for timeout...
Timeout Error caught { timeout: true }
Withdraw has failed for config account FJXUQQ1LJjSgVN2ChC79kN1gN9e3BKbNpCkTVMTHR2CN Error: Timed out awaiting confirmation on transaction
Rejecting for timeout...
Timeout Error caught { timeout: true }
Withdraw has failed for config account HqxznK2VtoAMnaakA7YCr7Vok4Y6YnpmvNFVtQe9iwrK Error: Timed out awaiting confirmation on transaction
Congratulations, 0 config accounts have been successfully drained.
Now you kinda rich, please consider supporting Open Source developers.
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It is said in the docs that a withdraw is network intensive and therefore you should use a custom rpc.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend any?

Comment: https://docs.metaplex.com/community#rpc
Quicknode and Genesys are currently the favorites

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

So, withdrawing is a heavy task and thus, you should use a custom RPC or a one faster than the public RPC.

You can try using [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/).

But if you want a free and fast one, I recommend using the GenesysGo RPC

- `https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/` (Mainnet)
- `https://devnet.genesysgo.net/` (Devnet)

If none of them works, try increasing the transaction timeout settings:)